# operating on two data frames of different length based on dates in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

df1

```
Revenue  EPS epsdate
100      5   2016-01-14
200      4   2016-04-14
```

df2

```
date          price
2016-01-15     16 
2016-01-16     18
2016-01-17     19
2016-04-15     24
2016-04-16     28
```

I want to create a vector where price is divided by previous available eps.   So:
2016-01-15, 2016-01-16 and 2016-01-17 price should be divided by 2016-01-14 EPS  and
2016-04-15, 2016-04-16 price should be divided by 2016-04-14 EPS.
Both the data sets contain large number of rows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cut` function to create a group variable on both data frame and then match the price and corresponding EPS based on that group. In detail, it could be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df2$group <- as.integer(cut(df2$date, breaks = c(df1$epsdate, max(df2$date) + 1)))
df1$group <- seq_along(df1$epsdate)

adjPrice <- merge(df1, df2, by = "group") %>% mutate(newPrice = price / EPS) %>% 
            select(newPrice) %>% as.vector
adjPrice
  newPrice
1      3.2
2      3.6
3      3.8
4      6.0
5      7.0
```

Comment: You need to make sure the date column in both data frame is of Date class. If not, using "df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)" to convert firstly. Check the same thing for df2 which would be "epsdate" correspondingly.